# precompile a query execution in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to improve the performance of the following codes in LINQ:

```
using (var db = new MyContext)
{ 
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
      Modal.StaffNo A = staff.StaffNo.Where(a => a.StaffType == staffType);
      staff.StaffNo.Add(A);
      ......
   }
}
```

I found it takes 1 sec to go through each item in the loop and then I figured out it's the first query expression "staff.StaffNo.Where(a => a.StaffType == staffType)" which takes most of the time. So I precompiled the query using "CompiledQuery.Compile" and it did save a lot of time.

However, the second query execution statement's execution time increased: "staff.StaffNo.Add(A);". Is there any way to precompiled that execution statement also?

Many Thanks !!!

Comment: Where is the ´q1´ query?

Comment: Sorry, i have changed the queries for better intrepretation

Comment: Your query doesn't really make sense to me, but how about just doing something similar to `staff.StaffNo.AddRange(staff.StaffNo.Where(a => items.Contains(a.StaffType)))` so you don't need to scan the collection (or table if you mean to select from the context) more than once?